# How Toggle opacity on Marker and tooltip at the same time?

Tags: leaflet

I have this code that changes the opacity of the marker when clicked.

```
var z3_ore_a2 = L.marker(map.unproject([424, 3386], map.getMaxZoom()), {icon: lapis_icon}).bindTooltip(" 
<b>x4</b>", {className: 'map_tooltip2', permanent: true,  direction: 'center', offset: 
L.point(15,2)}).openTooltip().on('click', oreOnClick);

function oreOnClick(e)
{
var oremarker = e.target;
   if(oremarker.options.opacity === 1){
       oremarker.setOpacity(0.3);
   } else {
       oremarker.setOpacity(1);
   }
}
```

I wanted to do the same thing on my tooltip, but this code only changes the marker and not the tooltip, how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the opacity for the tooltip too. You can access the tooltip object over the marker `marker.getTooltip()`

```
function oreOnClick(e){
var oremarker = e.target;
   if(oremarker.options.opacity === 1){
       oremarker.setOpacity(0.3);
       oremarker.getTooltip().setOpacity(0.3);
   } else {
       oremarker.setOpacity(1);
       oremarker.getTooltip().setOpacity(1);
   }
}
```

Comment: This is your periodic reminder that, in Leaflet, properties and methods prefixed by an underscore (`_`) are meant as private, and in this specific case it'd be a bit better to use the documented `.getTooltip()` method.

Comment: thanks, ill keep that in mind, I'm very new to leaflet and I had fun learning javascript because of it.